# How to get type of proxy authentication scheme on proxy server while using winapi?

Tags: winapi, download, rpc, microsoft-bits, proxy-authentication

I want to download a file using BITS or any other asynchronous file download winapi. Can anyone suggest any method to identify the proxy authentication scheme on server so that I can act accordingly in my application. (For ex. either its NTLM or Kerberos or simple Basic Authentication, Digest Authentication or Passport ... etc. )